# FCM onMessageReceived() not called, even when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

**UPDATE**:

Apparently, if I hit "test on device" and supply the registration token, things work fine... still not sure how to handle new devices with the same app. I can add all of them manually, hit the "test on device" button, and they will all receive the message, but if I hit the "publish" button and choose the app, only the first one receives the message.

==========================================================================

I'm trying to integrate FCM into my app.

My app is in **foreground**

I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042412/onmessagereceived-not-fired-when-app-in-foreground) first, however, this question is 10 months old, and it doesn't seem like extending FirebaseIDService is required anymore.

I have the google-services.json set up correctly

I added the correct dependencies to my project .gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
```

As well as to the app .gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the service I added to my manifest:

```
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This is the service I'm extending:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService()
{
    companion object {
        const val TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT = "token_refreshed_event"
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
        Log.d("MyFcmMessagingService", "Refreshed token: " + token!!)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(Intent(TOKEN_REFRESHED_EVENT))
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        Log.d("MyFcmMessagingService", "From: " + remoteMessage!!.from!!)
    }
}
```

The onNewToken method works just fine.
When I'm trying to send out a Notification from the Firebase console, nothing happens.

Comment: not sure if it helps, I found this: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background